# Git clone not working inside Docker build despite SSH credentials present

Tags: git, docker, ssh, bitbucket

I'm attempting to clone a repository into an image from a machine where I'm successfully able to use SSH to clone the repository outside of the Docker build. However, every time I attempt to clone the repository I get denied with the following excuse:

```
Cloning into 'my-repo'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu as my-repo

ARG GIT_SSH_KEY
ARG GIT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY
ARG KNOWN_HOSTS

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git ssh

# populate id_rsa files, populate known_hosts and config files, and manage permissions
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh/ && \
    chmod 700 ~/.ssh && \
    touch ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    touch ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    touch ~/.ssh/config && \
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config && \
    echo "${GIT_SSH_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    echo "${GIT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    echo "${KNOWN_HOSTS}" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    echo "Host bitbucket.example.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" > ~/.ssh/config && \
    git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com/my-repo.git && \
    rm ~/.ssh/*
```

I have verified that the Arguments passed in are making it as the same values as those fields on my local machine by debugging with echos. Furthermore, running `git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com/my-repo.git` works fine on the machine.

What am I missing that causes the permission to be denied? It states publickey as the reason but the `id_rsa.pub` is correctly populated.

EDIT: here is the docker command
`docker build --build-arg GIT_SSH_KEY="$GIT_SSH_KEY" --build-arg GIT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY="$GIT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" --build-arg KNOWN_HOSTS="$KNOWN_HOSTS" -f myRepoDockerfile -t myRepo .`

I obtained all of the environment variables by running things such as
`KNOWN_HOSTS='cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts'`

Comment: Does your SSH key pair have a password?

Comment: (a) What exactly does your `docker build` command line look like?  (b) Your public key has nothing to do with this.  You use the *private* key on your host to authenticate against the *public* key stored on bitbucket.  (c) How have you verified the contents of the private key file in the container?

Comment: @John no, when I run the git clone on my local machine outside of docker it doesn't ask me for a password, it begins the download right away

Comment: @larsks a.) updated OP b.) I've imported the private key into the docker build too c.) I have by running cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa within the build to debug and the contents there are the same as the contents on my machine

Comment: Does setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v'` in the build environment yield any useful information? This will run `ssh -v` when cloning the repository which may provide some useful diagnostics. What if you remove the `git clone...` and the `rm` from your `RUN` command, and then start a shell in the resulting image and try things by hand? Are you 100% certain you're using the correct key (for example, are you sure that success on your host does not depend on the fact that you have the key loaded into your ssh-agent)?

Comment: Thank you both, and especially @larsks! As it turns out there was a password associated with my key pair. It wouldn't ask me for for the password outside of a docker container but would within the docker container. During a build, since no password was provided, it just immediately failed the git pull but didn't give a detailed error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out there was a password associated with my key pair. It wouldn't ask me for for the password outside of a docker container but would within the docker container. The reason for that is that my `ssh-key` was already unlocked and loaded into `ssh-agent` with `ssh-add` by my distribution (which I could see with `ssh-add -l`).

If `ssh-add -l` doesn't turn up any results, it's still possible that there is a password associated with the key. This was the case for me. The best way to be sure is to check the `rsa_id private key` files (details below).

During a build, since no password was provided, it just immediately failed the git pull but didn't give a detailed error message. Once I generated an `id_rsa keypair` without an associated password and used that, I was able to clone into the docker build.

To check whether the password protection is the problem you can compare the `rsa_id private key` files, password protected ones look like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,2895AF2DB67AF43E94DF3C097C69B693

YUtMfSyL4xna /* lots of numbers and letters */
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

While those unprotected lack the lines number two to four lines containing Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED and alike

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAK /* lots of letters and numbers */
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: @Gunee I would love to but the system is making me wait 2 days before I can